# Connecting to Squid server using NTLM auth with Indy components

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

Has anybody managed to successfully connect to a *https* location via Squid proxy server setup with NTLM authentication, using Indy (10.XX) components?

I can successfully connect to http locations, however with https Indy returns an EAbort error.

Also, I can access http/https equally well if I use FreeProxy as the proxy server (with NTLM authentication). However Squid NTLM + https does not work? Anybody got this to work?

Thanks
Rael

Comment: We aleady covered this dicussion in the Indy forums.  You are getting the EAbort because the Squid server is not always sending back an authentication challenge to Indy's HTTP requests.

Comment: I have a code that works very well. It took me a while to understand why Indy was not capable of handle requests to Squid. But i dont have the source right now, I will return to this post tomorrow and post a sample.

Answer (score 1):

Here I am

1 - First of all, make sure you have updated indy's source.

2 - Download the SSL dlls from here [Indy SLL DLLS](http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/) and put them in your app output

3 - Make sure you have a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` connected to the `TidHttp` `IOHandler` property with the follow properties configured:

```
SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
OnVerifyPeer := SSLIOHandlerVerifyPeer;
SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [sslvrfPeer];
SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 2;
```

4 - Write this event:

```
function SSLIOHandlerVerifyPeer(Certificate: TIdX509; AOk: Boolean; ADepth, AError:    Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
end;
```

5 - Include these units to your uses clause:

```
IdAuthentication, IdAuthenticationDigest, IdAuthenticationNTLM
```

6 - Set the `TidHttp.OnProxyAuthorization`event to this:

```
procedure IdHTTPProxyAuthorization(Sender: TObject; Authentication: TIdAuthentication; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  Handled := False;
end;
```

7 - Set those properties:

```
IndyHttpClient.HTTPOptions := IndyHttpClient.HTTPOptions + [hoKeepOrigProtocol] + [hoInProcessAuth];
IndyHttpClient.ProtocolVersion := pv1_1;
IndyHttpClient.ProxyParams.ProxyServer := 'you proxy address here'
IndyHttpClient.ProxyParams.ProxyPort := 8080;
IndyHttpClient.ProxyParams.ProxyUsername := 'your proxy username here';
IndyHttpClient.ProxyParams.ProxyPassword := 'your proxy psw here';
```

Now you are good to go. This code will also work with Microsoft ISA Server. If you want me to, i can send to you the full source code of my component. I will not post it here because it was written in portuguese (unless someone says its ok to post).

Comment: Can you post the code here? I need to authenticate With Indy 10 ( no SSL Needed ) . I am stuck in it for two days.